# rxjs performance array vs stream

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to the rxjs world and trying to get my head around it. My understanding is one of the reasons to use rxjs is to improve performance with large datasets.

I'm trying to measure the speed improvement that you could get vs normal arrays high functions (map, reduce).

I have set up this example here https://jsbin.com/bagoli/edit?js,console

The idea is to generate an array and apply some operators to it, measuring the time spent.

I don't understand why the stream calculation is always slower. Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would like to mention that the default behavior of `Rx.Observable.from` (and I believe `Rx.Observable.fromArray`) is to use the current thread scheduler. In cases where you would like to do a lot of processing on the main thread, you would probably want to specify a different scheduler (`Rx.Scheduler.default`) to avoid blocking the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Your `calculateWithStreams` function is async and will run in parallel to your Array function. Therefore making it slower. If you run them one at a time, the times are basically the same once you increase the Size a bit.

RxJS does of course have some overhead compared to native Arrays, but it makes up for it with lazy evaluation.

Also consider that the improvement isn't just in execution speed, but also memory usage. The Array version will always create a new array and will take up more memory.

Comment: Hi, Luka thank you for the info. I tried running them one at a time and the results are pretty much the same. I don't see a great difference. I was aware of the memory reduction which is already a plus but it seems there is no so much gain in speed with the reactive approach or I'm doing something wrong